# If Worksheet 1 and Worksheet 2 Match, copy to worksheet 3 - Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to create the following in excel using formula as I am not familiar with VBA.

I have worksheet 1 which contains all the accounts numbers relating to different companies, these are unique keys

Worksheet 2 contains all the users in the account which also have the account ID.

I want the 3 worksheet to see if account ID in worksheet 1, look at worksheet 2 if match copy column 1,2,3 across.

E.G.

Worksheet 1 = Column A2 contains Account ID 1234 |
Worksheet 2 =  Column A2 contains Account ID 1234, B2 = First Name, C2 = Last Name | Worksheet 3 = I want A2 = 1234, B2 = First Name, C2 = Last Name

Comment: Why are you involving Sheet1 at all if the account ID is in Sheet2? See the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. In Sheet3, you want a list of account IDs from column A in Sheet1. That account ID is used to check for a matching account ID in Sheet2 and return the values from columns B and C.

In Sheet3's A2 use the following formula,

```
=sheet1!A2
```

In Sheet3's B2 use the following formula,

```
=iferror(vlookup($a2, sheet2!$a:$c, column(b:b), false), "")
```

Copy or fill that right to C2 then fill A2:C2 down as far as you wish.

Comment: what does the column(b:b) do ??